# Convert tables to specified engine

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I'd like to create procedure to convert all tables in specified database and specific engine to different engine.

This is what I have:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CONVERT_TABLES //

CREATE PROCEDURE CONVERT_TABLES
(
    IN db_name CHAR(255),
    IN engine_from CHAR(255),
    IN engine_to CHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE table_name CHAR(255);

    DECLARE db_tables CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = db_name COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AND ENGINE = engine_from COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN db_tables;

    loop_tables: LOOP

        FETCH db_tables INTO table_name;

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE loop_tables;
        END IF;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', db_name, '.', table_name, ' ENGINE = ', engine_to );
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DROP PREPARE stmt;

    END LOOP;

END //
DELIMITER;

CALL CONVERT_TABLES( "dp_dev_web7", "MyISAM", "InnoDB" );
```

But I get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

//EDIT: Fixed collation error, updated code

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are comparing strings of different collations. to fix that you need to either change the collation in the database structure or use `COLLATE` to change it dynamically:

```
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA COLLATE utf8_general_ci = IFNULL(db_name,"")  COLLATE utf8_general_ci AND ENGINE COLLATE utf8_general_ci = IFNULL(engine_from,"") COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: This fixed problem with collation, but I now get another one
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: so some variable equals `NULL` and you can't use `=` with NULL's rather `IS NULL` is the correct form

Comment: Should I use '@' in front of the param names?

Comment: you can use IFNULL to check and replace NULL values. editing the answer now.

Comment: Those are procedure params, they are not NULL in this example, this should be done just to be safe, but I think it wont fix my problem.

Comment: so some other param is NULL. either make sure none of your variables are NULL or put IFNULL to surpress the error. we can't know which variables are NULL just by looking at them.

Comment: Tried your solution with IFNULL just to be sure, problem persists. Only thing that possibly could be NULL is "table_name".

Comment: you should do more debugging to find out which variable is NULL. hint: its one of the variables that is used in a query.